# Class of Ricci Form and first Chern class of canonical bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, projective-space, kahler-manifolds

Let $\mathbb{P}^n$ the projective space (or more general a
Kähler manifold $X$) and

$$\kappa = \bigwedge^n \Omega_X$$

the canonical line bundle, the top exterior power of the bundle of
holomorphic Kähler differentials.

The Levi-Civita connection corresponding to metric on $X$ gives
rise to a connection on $\kappa $. The curvature of this connection is
the two form defined by

$$ \rho(X ,Y) := Ric⁡ (JX,Y)$$

where $J$ is the complex structure map on the tangent bundle determined
by the structure of the Kähler manifold and $Ric(-,-)$
the [Ricci curvature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature#Definition_via_differentiation_of_vector_fields) .  [Claim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ricci_curvature#K%C3%A4hler_manifolds): The Ricci form
is a closed 2-form, *whose cohomology class is, up to a real constant factor,
the first Chern class of the canonical bundle*.

Could somebody sketch the proof or provide lecture notes
with a proof of this claim?

Comment: This is true for the curvature form of any hermitian metric on a holomorphic line bundle. See for example chapter V in Demailly https://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~demailly/manuscripts/agbook.pdf

Comment: So the complex structure is absolutely *neccessary* here and the statement
that for example for arbitrary smooth real manifolds 
the Chern class of canonical bundle coinsides with the class
of Ricci curvature (which can be defined for every smooth mfd) 
fails in this generality?

Comment: What’s the canonical bundle on an arbitrary smooth manifold? In general I think Chern-Weil theory says we can get away with having only a smooth complex line bundle and a Hermitian metric on it, but there’s no obvious candidate for the canonical bundle without a complex structure.

Comment: My idea was that a smooth manifold (or say at least if it's nice enough) can be interpreted naturally as a variety and we can associate a canonical bundle to it like here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_bundle and then try to compare it's associated class with the class of Ricci curvature. Or is even such comparison not always possible?